# Como puedo ejecutar un codigo SQL despues de un WHILE en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es que quiero ejecutar una serie de comandos `sql` despues de que se ejecute un `while` en mi codigo `php`.
Mi codigo `php`  lo que quiero conseguir és que despues de importar unos datos a mi tabla de `mysql` este la compare con la tabla antigua que habia y borre los datos que no estan en la nueva tabla.

La idea de la funcion del `php` con las tablas es la siguiente:

```
alumnos          alumnosImport            alumnos       alumnosImport
id   name        id   name                id   name     id   name
1    Oriol       1    Oriol       ->      1    Oriol    1    Oriol
2    Ricard                    Code PHP
```

Mi codigo `php` es el siguiente:

```
<?php

class csv extends mysqli {

    private $state_csv = false;
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct("localhost","","","");

        if ($this->connect_error) {
            echo "File to connect Database: ". $this ->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function import($file=''){
        $file = fopen($file, 'r');

        while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {

            $value = '"'. implode('","', $row) .'"';
            $q = "INSERT INTO alumnosImport(id,name) VALUES(". $value .")";
            $this->query($q);
        }

        /*
        Codigo sql que quiero implementar: DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE alumnos.id NOT IN (SELECT alumnosImport.id FROM alumnosImport)
        */
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Sí, y ¿qué pasa?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Mi pregunta es que codigo php tengo que utilizar en ese hueco que falta no se que codigo tengo que poner.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que he tenido que poner es el siguiente:

```
 while {}

 $compareOperatore = "DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE alumnos.id NOT IN (SELECT alumnosImport.id FROM alumnosImport)";
 $this->query($compareOperatore);
```